# Plot the the marginal effects for each explanatory variables in R (ordered probit)

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, marginal-effects

I'm running an ordered probit regression analysis. I've now calculated the marginal effects for each explanatory variable on my dependent variable (DV=0,1,2) using the `erer` package in R.

Now, my question is how do I plot the marginal effects? The plot that I want to get is similar to this one  [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/probitlogit-marginal-effects-in-r/).

I use the command `polr`to estimate the ordered probit regression. I have both continuous and dichotomous explanatory variables in the model.

My model looks something like this: `model<-polr(y~x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,data=mydata,Hess=TRUE, method="probit")`
for the marginal effects I use simple the command from `erer` package: `MEs<–ocME(model)`

All comments are very welcome. Please have in mind though that I'm asking a question that is related to ordered probit regression analysis.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have a look at packages `coefplot` and `coefplot2`